# Consulta Datatables suma de columna

Tags: php, datatable

Perdon soy nuevo en PHP y estoy haciendo Datatables lo suma al valor de la columna pero no puedo redondear el valor me da con muchos decimales adjunto el script que se usa para configurar la suma

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $('#sampleTable').DataTable( {
        "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {
            var api = this.api(), data;

            // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
            var intVal = function ( i ) {
                return typeof i === 'string' ?
                    i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                    typeof i === 'number' ?
                        i : 0;
            };

            // Total over all pages
            total = api
                .column( 3 )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );

            // Total over this page
            pageTotal = api
                .column( 3, { page: 'current'} )
                .data()
                .reduce( function (a, b) {
                    return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                }, 0 );

            // Update footer
            $( api.column( 3 ).footer() ).html(
                 '$'+pageTotal +' ( $'+ total +' total)'
            );
        }
    } );


</script>
```

Comment: Mi opinion seria si los datos los traes desde mysql/sq server..etc.. podrias ya traer esa consulta sumada .. y tan solo los mostrarias en tu datatables..

Comment: incluso hasta lo podrias retornar redondeado la cantidad de tu bd

Comment: seria bueno si mostraras la estructura de tu tabla de la base de datos .. la que deseas sumar y redondear

Comment: La tabla contiene los datos en formato decimal #.## en mysql seria arriesgado cambiar el formato porque son muchos registros..Lo que necesito es mostrar el datatable con el plugin de suma si se puede con el mismo formato

Answer (score 0):

Puedes agregar lo siguiente al resultado:

`pageTotal.toFixed(2)`

Con esto puedes redondear los decimales a la cantidad que desees mostrar.

Y el resultado sería el siguiente:

Antes pageTotal= 1542.199123

Después de aplicar toFixed()

pageTotal = 1542.20